# Eliminate variables from equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, equations

I want to eliminate variables from an equation using MATLAB. For example, lets consider the following equations:

```
p = (m + n)
q = (m - n)
r = (m^3 - n^3)
```

Now, `r` could be expressed in terms of `p` and `q` by entirely eliminating `m` and `n` like this: `r = (3*p^2*q + q^3)/4`.

This can be achieved in Mathematica using the following method:

```
Eliminate[{p == (m + n), q == (m - n), r == (m^3 - n^3)}, {m, n}]
```

How can I get the same result in MATLAB if it is possible at all. Switching between different applications just for this is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```matlab
% Declare symbolic variables
syms m n p q

% Solve m,n 
s1=solve(m+n-p==0,m-n-q==0,m,n);

% Substitute variables with obtained solution
r = (m^3 - n^3);
r2=subs(subs(r,m,s.m),n,s.n);

% simplify answer
r3=simplify(r2)
```

Comment: So the steps that I need to follow are: solve the equations in terms of desired variables and then substitute them in the final equation. I am guessing the same would apply for three or more variables as well. :)

Comment: @iKnowNothing yes indeed. This is not 2 variable specific. MATLABs symbolic toolbox is not as advanced as Mathematica, so you need to think which steps do you need to take and program them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the both equation and find the values for `p` and `q`. Then `subs` function will give the solution by substituting `m` & `n` by `p` & `q`. [More information available here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)

```
eqn1 = r == (m^3 - n^3);
eqn2 = p == (m + n);
eqn3 = q == (m - n);

eqn4 = isolate(eqn2,m);  
eqn5 = isolate(eqn3,m);
eqn6 = rhs(eqn2) == rhs(eqn3);
eqn6 = isolate(eqn4,n);   %solving for n
eqn7 = subs(eqn4,lhs(eqn6),rhs(eqn6)); %solving for m

eqn1 = subs(eqn1,lhs(eqn6),rhs(eqn6));  %substituting n
eqn1 = subs(eqn1,lhs(eqn7),rhs(eqn7));  %subtituting m
```

Comment: opps, did not see you answer. Ill leave mine here for the moment as it seems shorter

Comment: yeah. your's one is much simpler. May be I have made things complicated.